# How to find out "The most popular repositories" on Github?

Tags: github

Once upon a time, we can watch the most popular repositories (Most forked or Most watched) at this page (https://github.com/popular/watched) of Github. like this:

[image: img]

But now when you try to explore repos, you can only see the Top 25 trending repositories. like this: https://github.com/trending

Why Github change this, and
is there any way to find out the list of the most popular repos?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/trending?l=lua&since=weekly

Comment: You can collect the data yourself using some GitHub API script, such as https://github.com/vmarkovtsev/GitHubStars

Comment: All the raw data to query this by any ranking you devise is available in BigQuery. For example, how to find the top projects per country: https://medium.com/@hoffa/the-top-github-projects-per-country-92c275e19409

Comment: You can also [watch trending repositories](https://github.com/vitalets/github-trending-repos) separated per programming language.

Comment: @MikhailBoyarsky That address is now redirecting to a phishy website.

Comment: Most popular by [**number of forks**](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=stars:%3E1&s=forks&type=Repositories). Most popular by [**number of stars**](https://github.com/search?q=stars%3A%3E100&s=stars&type=Repositories). A quick way to see *your* most starred libraries, go to your profile page and click 'Customize your pins', it will show your repos ordered most stars to least.

Answer (score 18):

Ranking by stars or forks is **not** working. Each promoted or created by a famous company repository is popular at the beginning. Also it is possible to have a number of them which are in trend right now (publications, marketing, events). It doesn't mean that those repositories are useful/popular.

The [gitmostwanted.com](http://gitmostwanted.com/) project ([repo at github](https://github.com/kkamkou/gitmostwanted.com)) analyses [GH Archive](https://www.gharchive.org/) data in order to highlight the most interesting repositories and exclude others. Just compare the results with mentioned resources.