# Find most followed repos in GitHub

Tags: github

How can I find the most followed repos in GitHub?

I know that you can see the most starred using `stars:>1` and sorting by stars or I can see the most forked repos sorting by number of forks as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855552/how-to-find-out-the-most-popular-repositories-on-github?rq=1), but I can't find a way to get the most followed ones.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is here on the [official developer docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/). It says you must `sort` by followers and `order` by descending.

Comment: You cannot sort by followers.

Comment: Really... It's refering just to users search. Indeed I can't see how you are going to get this done. The documentation makes no mention of this parameter for a repositories search.

Comment: This is the reason why I am asking. If it was in the docs I would have just used it.

Comment: You have to get the followers page for each repo and sort by that number. I thought somebody already did this.